# Unexpected results measuring AC from secondary of toroid transformer

Tags: ac, transformer, multimeter

I am trying to measure AC voltage from the secondary of a toroid power transformer, and I am baffled by what I am seeing.  The AC measurement (less than 4 volts) is too low; the transformer is rated at 50vct, and the DC output is 71 volts, measured after rectification/filtering.

I built a test rig for transformers that is fused, includes a rectifier/filter board for DC, and terminal strips to create a dummy load from power resistors, but for this test, no load was used.

The transformer is an Avel Lindberg AV-67530 toroid, 50VCT 2A.  It has two primaries, allowing it to work with 120vac or 240vac; I have tested using only one primary, and again with both primaries wired in parallel according to the polarity from the specs, with similar results.

The rectifier/filter board (see schematic) has a 600v 6A full-wave bridge rectifier and four 680uF @ 70v filter capacitors in series/parallel.  It can test both single-pole and bipolar supplies, depending on whether the transformer has a center tap in the secondary; COM is only used for bipolar testing.

[image]

A red LED with a 2.4k 1/2W resistor is connected between + and COM, a green LED with resistor for - and COM, and a white from + to -, with two 2.4K 1/2W resistors in series; the LEDs are the only load in this test.

Measuring the AC of the transformer secondary, and the DC output of the rectifier/filter, with four DMMs I have, I get the following results:

- Wavetek 5XL: AC 0.1v (stable), DC about 71v
- BK 2707A: AC 2.2 to 3.1v (varies!), DC about 78v
- Sinometer MS8268: AC about 2.4v (varies), DC about 71v
- DMiotech Smart-V: AC 3.1v (varies), DC about 71v

The Wavetek is an old DMM that I have had for years.  The BK is a more recent purchase, as are the two Chinese DMMs.

The AC measurements (less than 4 volts) are much too low for the DC output (more than 70 volts) I see.  The AC is the same if I disconnect the transformer from the rectifier board.  The AC readings do not always settle down, and on the BK there is a variation as much as one volt, but the DC readings settle down quickly, aside from some fluctuation of the least significant digit.

The DC measurement is slightly higher than I would expect from multiplying (rated) 50v AC by 1.414 and subtracting for rectifier voltage drop, but it is in the ballpark.  I do not understand why the BK 2702A reads 10% higher for DC than the others.

When using other, conventional (E/I iron core) transformers, I get expected results for both AC and DC.

Why am I getting such low readings when measuring the AC output of the secondary of a toroid transformer?

Comment: The only possible answer is "you're doing something wrong in your measurement". 70-ish-V DC measurement is sensible, so your transformer is working. Check that you have your voltmeters setup correctly.

Comment: That's what I thought, too, so I was extra careful about the various ways the meters have to be set up to measure AC.  I am convinced I am measuring correctly (same as I do for conventional transformers), and I get similar results from four different DMMs.

Comment: Are your meters rated to measure AC mains? If so, what do you see on the primary side?

Comment: Have you switched the knob on DMM to ACV?

Comment: Just now, I set the BK meter (which I consider the best) to 200v, and the slide switch to AC.
1. Measuring across the secondary, it says 0.5v
2. Measuring the mains, it says 120v
Then I switch to DC
3. Measuring the output, it says 77v

Comment: Mark both ends of the voltmeter connection on your schematic for the AC measurement.

Comment: The voltmeter connections: using AC mode: first, across the mains (120v), second, across the secondary (same as the ~ marks on the bridge, 0.5v), and third, using DC mode, from + to - on the output (77v).  In all three cases, the range is set to 200v.

Comment: I think the 'it varies' comment is the key. It suggests you are not measuring between the points you think you are, but between one point and another, perhaps capacitively coupled, point, to get a dodgy reading. Measuring through solder flux can make the reading wrong as well. Try putting the probes on the clean metal non-soldered part of the rectifier '~' terminals.

Comment: I am using the sharp-ended probes to touch onto the screws of the terminal strip to which the secondary is connected.  No solder.  Also, the same methodology works fine with the other transformers, and I do get clean readings from the line voltage screws, and the DC screws.

Comment: Measure the AC voltage from the transformer centre tap to each of the ~ terminals on the bridge. It may be that only one of the halves of the secondary is working.